# WSO2 Api Manager - Generating REST APIs from SOAP

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

WSO2 API Manager version: 2.1.0

This link suggests that it is possible to generate REST APIs from a SOAP Endpoint: https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=85372237

Like this:
https://docs.wso2.com/download/attachments/85372237/pass-through.png?version=2&modificationDate=1517401519000&api=v2

I cannot post images yet so I am including the link above

However, when I select the radio button for the Soap Endpoint, I do not see the radio buttons for the following two options:
1. Pass Through 
2. Generate REST APIs

How do I get those two options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not available in wso2am 2.1.0 version. It is a feature that will be available with wso2am 2.2.0.

APIM 2.2.0 is not yet released. But you can try this in a milestone release found at https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/releases/tag/v2.1.0-update10.

Download the pack from https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/releases/download/v2.1.0-update10/wso2am-2.1.0-update10.zip

Comment: Thanks Anuruddha Lanka Liyanarachchi... greatly appreciate your help.